# Mysql: Round datetime to seconds - some issues 24h

Tags: mysql, sql, rounding

i spend time to solve my issue on my own and also read through many posts in here but somehow i cannot find a working solution for me.

I'm collecting different values from my smarthome in an mysqldb. To run some analysis on the data i need to round a datetime value in one usecase. I must get rid of the seconds.

What I tried/found where different approaches (even via Unixtime) but nothing solved my issue. Within this forum i found an old thread with the following hint:

extract from my insert script:

```
CONVERT(
CONCAT(
    date(`detailed-data-integration`.`timestamp`),
    ' ',
    SEC_TO_TIME((ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(`detailed-data-integration`.`timestamp`)/60)) * 60)    
) , Datetime) AS `timestamp-rnd`
```

This looks fine and works on the first view, but: 
Timestamp: 2018-02-03 23:59:56 leads to a NULL because of an invalid datetime value. The function wants to create: 2018-02-03 24:00:00 which is wrong.

Can somebody of you give me a hint how to handle / solve this issue?

Thx and KR

Comment: Use `floor()` instead of `round()`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, floor() makes the situation bette but has another sideeffect. E.g. yyyy-mm-dd 14:55:31 is "modified" to yyyy-mm-dd 14:55:00. I expect the value to be yyyy-mm-dd 14:56:00. Did I made a mistake by using floor? I just replaced it in my statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `time_to_sec()`?  You should be using `to_seconds()`

```
'0000-01-01' + interval round(to_seconds(`detailed-data-integration`.`timestamp`)/60)) * 60) second - interval 1 day as `timestamp-rnd`
```

In other words, don't separate the date from the time.  Just handle the entire date/time as a single value.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your feedback. I tried to do it like this but i'm struggeling with your comment. I tried to replace the wrong function and I tried to use your total statement. can you see my mistake? 

SELECT `detailed-data-integration`.`id`,
    `detailed-data-integration`.`timestamp`,
    
    CONVERT(
    CONCAT(
  date(`detailed-data-integration`.`timestamp`),
        ' ', '0000-01-01' + interval
  to_seconds((round(to_seconds(`detailed-data-integration`.`timestamp`)/60)) * 60)    
 ) , Datetime) AS `timestamp-rnd`
        
FROM `sbfspot-man`.`detailed-data-integration`;

Answer (score 0):

i identified a solution which will work for my requirements which i want to share with you:

```
    CASE 
    when second(`detailed-data`.`timestamp`) >= 30 then DATE_FORMAT(`detailed-data`.`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') + interval 1 minute
    when second(`detailed-data`.`timestamp`) < 30 then DATE_FORMAT(`detailed-data`.`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
END as testcase
```